# Updating a column with JSON data in another table

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have seen a lot on JSON and SQL Server but haven't been able to find what I am looking for.

I want to update columns in one table by retrieving JSON values from another table.

Lets say I have the below table:

**table : people**

```
+-------+-----------+
|   id  |   name    |  
+-------+-----------+
|   1   |   John    |      
|   2   |   Mary    |     
|   3   |   Jeff    |       
|   4   |   Bill    |       
|   5   |   Bob     |   
+-------+-----------+
```

And lets pretend I have another table filled with rows of JSON like the following:

**table : archive**

```
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|   id  |   json                                                         |  
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|   1   |[{ "Column":"name","values": { "old": "Jeff", "new": "John"}}]  |      
|   2   |[{ "Column":"name","values": { "old": "Rose", "new": "Mary"}}]  |     
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now the idea is to change Johns name to Jeff.

```
UPDATE people
SET name = JSON_QUERY(archive.json, '$values.old')
WHERE ID = 1
```

The above SQL may make no sense but I'm just trying to get across my current logic of what I'm trying to do. I hope it makes some sense.

If more information is needed please ask.

Comment: Two remarks: Am I correct, that you mixed *old* and *new* values? And am I correct, that the above is just a sample and you are looking for a generic solution, where the updates might affect different columns, maybe even more than one per row? At least the JSON would allow more elements in the object-array.

Answer (score 1):

You can read your json using `openjson` and a double `cross apply` with `with` clause. Then you can use an `update from` to change the values in `@people`:

```
declare @people table (id int, [name] varchar(50))

insert into @people values
 (1, 'John')    
,(2, 'Mary')   
,(3, 'Jeff')     
,(4, 'Bill')     
,(5, 'Bob' )

declare @json table  (id int, [json] nvarchar(max))
insert into @json values
 (1,'[{ "Column":"name","values": { "old": "Jeff", "new": "John"}}]')     
,(2,'[{ "Column":"name","values": { "old": "Rose", "new": "Mary"}}]')    

update @people
set [name] = d.old
from @people p
inner join 
(
     select id
          , c.old
          , c.new
     from @json a
     cross apply openjson(json) with 
     (
         [Column] nvarchar(50)
       , [values] nvarchar(MAX) as JSON
     ) b
     cross apply openjson(b.[values]) with 
     (
         old nvarchar(50)
       , new nvarchar(50)
     ) c
) d 
on p.id = d.id
```

Before update:

[image]

After update:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I asked you some questions in a comment above

> Two remarks: Am I correct, that you mixed old and new values? And am I
>   correct, that the above is just a sample and you are looking for a
>   generic solution, where the updates might affect different columns,
>   maybe even more than one per row? At least the JSON would allow more
>   elements in the object-array.

But - as a start - you can try this:

--mockup your set-up (thanks @Andrea, I used yours)

```
declare @people table (id int, [name] varchar(50))

insert into @people values
 (1, 'John')    
,(2, 'Mary')   
,(3, 'Jeff')     
,(4, 'Bill')     
,(5, 'Bob' )

declare @json table  (id int, [json] nvarchar(max))
insert into @json values
 (1,'[{ "Column":"name","values": { "old": "Jeff", "new": "John"}}]')     
,(2,'[{ "Column":"name","values": { "old": "Rose", "new": "Mary"}}]')
```

--This will - at least - return everything you need. The rest is - assumably - dynamic statement building and `EXEC()`:

```
SELECT p.*
      ,A.[Column]
      ,JSON_VALUE(A.[values],'$.old') AS OldValue
      ,JSON_VALUE(A.[values],'$.new') As NewValue
FROM @people p
INNER JOIN @json j ON p.id=j.id
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j.[json]) 
WITH([Column] VARCHAR(100), [values] NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON) A;
```

The result (old and new seems to be mistaken):

```
id  name    Column  OldValue    NewValue
1   John    name    Jeff        John
2   Mary    name    Rose        Mary
```